# Django Replace choices value in ModelForm Widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have a model that let me to choice between some predefined values.

```
in models.py

class Customer(models.Model):
    GENDER = ( ('m' , 'Male') , ('f' , 'Female') )
    PersonGender = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=GENDER)
```

and i have a ModelForm to handle my form , it's ok , but i want to define another ModelForm To Change "GENDER" values for some reasons.

i define another ModelForm in forms.py

```
GENDER = (('male' , 'Male' ), ('female' , 'Female') )
class MySecondaryForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Customer
            fields = '__all__'
            widgets = {
                'PersonGender': forms.Select(choices=GENDER)
            }
```

with this configuration Drop-down menu not changes to new values.

i can fix it with below configuration:

```
GENDER = (('male' , 'Male' ), ('female' , 'Female') )
class MySecondaryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    PersonGender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

with above configuration Drop-down values changes to my new , but i want to know how can i change it inside the Meta Class in "widgets"  ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not define GENDER in forms.py and model.py. Just define it in models.py.

```
class MySecondaryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

is sufficent for your form. Worst thing you can do in python is using things that you dont need.

Regarding to your comment maybe this would be an option as described here :

```
http://www.ilian.io/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/
```

Quoted code from this article

```
def get_my_choices():
    # you place some logic here
    return choices_list

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_choice_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=get_my_choices() )
```

Comment: GENDER in models.py already defined , i want to override this  in forms.py and inside the Meta widgets attribute.

Comment: see the modification of the answer

Comment: Yes , i know i can replace the values by "def" method and another way that i mentioned in the question , but i want to know the method for defining the widget inside the Meta class which keep other elements which defined in the model such as required or help text or ....

Comment: thats the only way I know