# Remove choice from ModelForm Select widget

Tags: django, django-forms

In my model I have multiple choices like:

```
class Choice_Test(models.Model):
    TESTS = (('1', 'A'),('2', 'B'),)
    option = models.CharField(choices=TESTS, max_length=1)
```

and it's form:

```
class Choice_TestCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice_Test
        fields=['option']
        widgets={'option': forms.Select()}
```

in the template:

```
<label id="options">Options</label>
{{ form_options.option }}
```

How can I remove the 'A' value from the select output?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647930/django-replace-choices-value-in-modelform-widget) but it didn't work for me.

**Edit: Adding view code snippet**

```
if choices_exist:
        choice_form = Choice_TestCreateForm(new_choices=(('1','Z'),),
                                            instance=choice_instance)
        choice_form.initial['random_value'] = '99'
    else:
        choice_form = Choice_TestCreateForm(new_choices=(('1','Z'),))
```

Comment: @YannicHamann will comment/vote/mark your answer as soon as I can replicate it, I ended up using jQuery to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you apply changes to the choices in the view and then pass them to the `Choice_TestCreateForm`. You could also move the logic to your model/`services.py` and call this newly implemented function in the view.

`forms.py`:

```
class Choice_TestCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice_Test
        fields = ['option']
        widgets = {'option': forms.Select()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_choices = kwargs.pop('new_choices')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['option'].choices = new_choices
```

`views.py`:

```
class NewCreateView(CreateView):

    model = Choice_Test
    form_class = Choice_TestCreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['new_choices'] = (('1', 'A'),)
        return form_kwargs
```

---

**Update**

Function based view:

```
def func_view(request):
    form = Choice_TestCreateForm(new_choices=(('1', 'Y'),))
    return render(request, template_name='template.html', context={'form': form})
```

Comment: Our current project isn't using Class Based Views, we are using Function Based Views =/

Comment: I guess it would look something like this in your function based view: ``form = Choice_TestCreateForm(new_choices=(('1', 'A'),))``, then you pass the form to the context of the  ``render`` method.

Comment: This particular view code is around 1,000 lines long.. I'll post the part where the form is instanced.